# How do i create rich text editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, plugins

I will be straight to the point how do i design [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p78Xk.jpg) with css and html or are they external plugins I can use to achieve this. What we write our questions on stackoverflow. I have a client that needs this on their blog area

Comment: are you looking for a wysiwyg editor like [tinymce](https://www.tinymce.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

It is called it rich text editor and uses JS/jQuery, (or some other languages), to make it what it is.

After inspecting it, it looks like this text area is custom made, requiring much time and expertise.

I would advise using a different rich text editor. I have normally used [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/), but you could also use [TinyMCE](https://www.tinymce.com/). There is a bunch more, just google ["rich text editor"](https://www.google.ca/search?q=rich+text+editor).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the best is, very easy to use and super powerful:

#### Example: https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/5nt56n0y/

HTML:

```
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.2/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>

<textarea name="editor1"></textarea>
```

JS:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
```

Offical site: http://ckeditor.com/